# Laravel 5.4 hide something from other users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on an application where the user has projects assigned to him, which he sees on his website. After clicking on a given project, it is moved to the page of this project where the url looks like eg ./project/22 - 22 is the id of the project. The problem is that another user entering in the search engine eg / project / 22 can see this project even though it is not assigned to it. I also have a pivot table where the project id and user id are stored. This is my code to show project:
Controller:

```
public function projects($id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
       return view('pages.project')->with('project', $project);
    }
```

Project model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

user model:

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

web.php:

```
 Route::get('/projects/{id}', 'PagesController@projects');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at the top of your controller:

```
$project = Project::findOrFail($id);
if (!$project->users->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first()) {
    App::abort(403, 'You cannot view this project.');
}
```

Comment: will need to add 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; at the top too